# How can I customize Login Page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, css, login

How can I customize the Login Page for Admin in Magento 2? 
I want to change the Logo and CSS Styles there.

Comment: Does you know any exp with rewrite template magento ???

Comment: I'm not on my work PC at the moment so I can't provide code, but you will need to make changes to the templates/XML in the Magento_Customer module. This is the XML you will need to extend - https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml. Do not edit this file, you need to extend it within your own theme. If you have any problems let me know and I'll provide some examples.

Comment: To modify the default admin logo with custom theme, [check here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/206125/61183).

Answer (score 2):

You propably have to add new theme for backend. Currently it is possible only by overwriting di.xml, so you must create new module, with sequence 'Magento_Theme'.

Then you have to create etc/adminhtml/di.xml file with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="themes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="adminhtml" xsi:type="string">Vendor/theme</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then create new theme in app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/theme with parent set for 'Magento/backend'. In this theme you can overwrite styles or .phtml files as it was frontend theme.