# Magento admin logo change!

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am trying to change Magento2.2.2 admin logo.
But no success.
This is what I have done:

This file `app/design/adminhtml/XXX/yyy/theme.xml` contains:

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
   <title>Xy_Theme</title>
   <parent>Magento/backend</parent>
</theme>
```

This file `app/design/adminhtml/XXX/yyy/registration.php` contains:

```
<?php
  \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
  \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
  'adminhtml/XXX/yyy',
  __DIR__
);
```

This file `app/design/adminhtml/XXX/yyy/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
  <title>Admin Title</title>
</head>
<body>        
  <referenceContainer name="header">
    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Page\Header" name="logo" before="-">
      <arguments>
        <argument name="show_part" xsi:type="string">logo</argument>
        <argument name="edition" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Community Edition</argument>
        <argument name="logo_image_src" xsi:type="string">images/my-logo.svg</argument>
        <argument name="logo_alt" xsi:type="string">My Admin</argument>
      </arguments>
    </block>            
  </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

And finally my logo image is in
`app/design/adminhtml/XXX/yyy/web/images/my-logo.svg`

Comment: To modify custom admin logos using module, [check here](https://github.com/theshreyas/magento-2-quickies/tree/main/Adminlogo)

Answer (score 7):

Try this code:

> 1. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/registration.php

```
<?php \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[VendorName]_[ModuleName]',
    __DIR__
);?>
```

> 2. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> 3. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="themes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="adminhtml" xsi:type="string">[VendorName]/[themename]</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> 4. app/design/adminhtml/[VendorName]/[themename]/registration.php

```
<?php \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'adminhtml/[VendorName]/[themename]',
    __DIR__
);?>
```

> 5. app/design/adminhtml/[VendorName]/[themename]/theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Theme Title</title>
    <parent>Magento/backend</parent>
</theme>
```

> 6. app/design/adminhtml/[VendorName]/[themename]/Magento_Backend/layout/admin_login.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-login" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles" />
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_image_src" xsi:type="string">images/login-logo.svg</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> 7. app/design/adminhtml/[VendorName]/[themename]/web/images/login-logo.svg
> 8. app/design/adminhtml/[VendorName]/[themename]/Magento_Backend/layout/default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header">
            <referenceBlock name="logo">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">300</argument> 
                    <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">300</argument>
                    <argument name="show_part" xsi:type="string">logo</argument>
                    <argument name="edition" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Community Edition</argument>
                    <argument name="logo_image_src" xsi:type="string">images/menu-logo.svg</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> 9. app/design/adminhtml/[VendorName]/[themename]/web/images/menu-logo.svg
> 10. Magento CLI

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

**Note:**

1. For Admin login page logo change, follow steps - 6 & 7
2. For Admin menu
   logo change, follow steps - 8 & 9

**Note:**
Feel free to use PNG files instead of SVG for logo.

**Note:**
If changes not reflected on Admin pages then try below steps:

1. Uninstall a manually added theme

   - `mysql -u <user> -p -e "delete from <dbname>.theme where theme_path ='<VendorName>/<themename>' AND area ='adminhtml' limit 1"`
2. Upgrades the Magento application, DB data, and schema

   - `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
   - `php bin/magento setup:di:compile - (Optional)`
   - `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`
   - `php bin/magento c:c && php bin/magento c:f`

Comment: Is it necessary to create `app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]` ? Only creating `adminhtml` theme won't work ?

Comment: @Vikram - To create admin theme, first you need to register it. For more detail, check links: [Create an Admin theme](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_create.html) & [Apply an Admin theme](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_apply.html).

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/207833/magento-2-modify-default-admin-logo-login-and-backend-menu-with-custom-theme